# Setting Values for State in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, semantic-ui

Good Afternoon,

I am having an issue setting an object via useState and I really do not understand why. Below is the input that I am using to display the information from the database based on the ?: statement. I am unsure why the state will not update, and it is possible that I am not handling the state properly. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```js
const [userUpdate, setUserUpdate] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    dob: "",
    gender: "",
    address: {
        billing: {
            address1: "",
            address2: "",
            city: "",
            state: "",
            postalCode: "",
        },
        shipping: {
            address1: "",
            address2: "",
            city: "",
            state: "",
            postalCode: "",
        },
    },
});
```

```js
<FormGroup widths="equal" id="billing">
    <FormField
      id="address1"
      control={Input}
      label="Address Line 1"
      placeholder="123 Main Street"
      defaultValue={
          userUpdate.address.billing.address1
            ? userUpdate.address.billing.address1
            : user.address.billing.address1
      }
      onBlur={(e) => {
          handleChange("b", e);
      }}
    />
</FormGroup>
```

The handleChange -> b is the section of the address that I need to update.. Billing or Shipping etc.

```js
const handleChange = (section, e) => {
    const form = e.target.form.id;

    if (form === "user") {
      console.log(section);
      if (section === "b") {
        setUserUpdate({
          ...userUpdate,
          address: {
            billing: {
              [e.target.id]: e.target.value.trim(),
            },
          },
        });
      } else if (section === "s") {
        setUserUpdate({
          ...userUpdate,
          address: {
            shipping: {
              [e.target.id]: e.target.value.trim(),
            },
          },
        });
      } else {
        setUserUpdate({
          ...userUpdate,
          [e.target.id]: e.target.value.trim(),
        });
      }
    }

    if (form === "category") {
      setCategoryUpdate({
        ...categoryUpdate,
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value.trim(),
      });
    }
  };
```

console log is showing the correct e.target.id => address1 and e.target.value.trim() => address, but its not updating the state..

now my code is throwing an error on the form default value

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address1')
GenerateActiveScreen
C:/Development/Picwrist Web Application/client/src/components/screens/user/Dashboard.js:397
  394 | control={Input}
  395 | label="Address Line 1"
  396 | placeholder="123 Main Street"
> 397 | defaultValue={
      | ^  398 |   userUpdate.address.shipping.address1
  399 |     ? userUpdate.address.shipping.address1
  400 |     : user.address.shipping.address1
```

Comment: Check the `user.address.billing.address1` in default value

Comment: It makes a call to the DB that sets the user record. The value is correct prior to making a change to the record. This fails with the onBlur event that happens when changing the existing value.. ie.. 123 Hills Drive is in the field from the DB, but I change it to 122 Hills Drive it fails

Comment: Everything else under the userUpdate object updates without issue, but its only the address section that is throwing the error.

Comment: Follow up.... Okay, so it looks like it is overriding all the address information. Say that you have all the address information it's not carrying the existing information through the update and leaving just billing.address1 as the only item under address object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed ID's for the fields and updated the handleChange state to pass the existing values from the previous state.

```
const handleChange = (section, e) => {
    const form = e.target.form.id;

    if (form === "user") {
      const id = e.target.id;
      const value = e.target.value.trim();

      if (section === "b") {
        setUserUpdate((userUpdate) => ({
          ...userUpdate,
          address: {
            ...userUpdate.address,
            billing: {
              ...userUpdate.address.billing,
              [id.slice(1)]: value,
            },
          },
        }));
      } else if (section === "s") {
        setUserUpdate((userUpdate) => ({
          ...userUpdate,
          address: {
            ...userUpdate.address,
            shipping: {
              ...userUpdate.address.shipping,
              [id.slice(1)]: value,
            },
          },
        }));
      } else {
        setUserUpdate({
          ...userUpdate,
          [e.target.id]: e.target.value.trim(),
        });
      }
    }

    if (form === "category") {
      setCategoryUpdate({
        ...categoryUpdate,
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value.trim(),
      });
    }
  };
```